# Counting the number of functions. Combinatorics problem.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ be an $n$ element set and let $i,j,k\in \mathbb{N}$ with $i+j+k=n.$ How many functions $f:A\to \{0,1,2\}$ are there for which there are exactly $i$ elements $a\in A$ that get mapped to $f(a)=0,$ exactly $j$ elements $a\in A$ with $f(a)=1$ and $k$ elements $a\in A$ with $f(a)=2$?

My Attempt: We look at $0$ and choose $i$ elements from the set $n,$ then we are left with $j+k$ elements.  From these many elements, we look at $1$ and choose $j$ elements from $j+k$ elements. Then we are left with $k$ elements, which are all mapped to $2.$ So we have the following formula   $$\binom{n}{i}\binom{j+k}{j}.$$  Is this correct?

Comment: Your answer is spot on and can be more neatly written as a multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{i,j,k}$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I recall reading about this thing, but never saw any application of this. Thanks for bringing this up again!

Comment: its trinomial and it is correct.